NDK 21.4.7075529 issues on ARM64 architecture
I'm a DevOps Engineer trying to build a Docker image using this Dockerfile on an ARM64 architecture.
This Dockerfile worked fine on Intel architecture, but when run on ARM64 it gives this error:
Warning: Failed to find package 'ndk;21.4.7075529'
#21 11.89 [===                                    ] 10% Computing updates...              
#21 ERROR: process "/dev/.buildkit_qemu_emulator /bin/sh -c yes | ./sdkmanager \"ndk;${NDK_VERSION_1}\" \"ndk;${NDK_VERSION_2}\" \"ndk;${NDK_VERSION_3}\" --sdk_root=/opt/cmdline-tools/latest/bin" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [18/23] RUN yes | ./sdkmanager "ndk;21.4.7075529" "ndk;23.1.7779620" "ndk;24.0.8215888" --sdk_root=/opt/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:
#21 11.89 [===                                    ] 10% Computing updates...              
#21 11.89 [===                                    ] 10% Computing updates...              
------
Dockerfile:147
--------------------
 145 |     RUN yes | ./sdkmanager "platforms;${SKD_PLATFORMS_1}" "platforms;${SKD_PLATFORMS_2}" "platforms;${SKD_PLATFORMS_3}" "platforms;${SKD_PLATFORMS_4}" --sdk_root=/opt/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
 146 |     
 147 | >>> RUN yes | ./sdkmanager "ndk;${NDK_VERSION_1}" "ndk;${NDK_VERSION_2}" "ndk;${NDK_VERSION_3}" --sdk_root=/opt/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
 148 |     
 149 |     RUN yes | ./sdkmanager "cmake;${CMAKE_VERSION_1}" "cmake;${CMAKE_VERSION_2}" --sdk_root=/opt/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
--------------------
error: failed to solve: process "/dev/.buildkit_qemu_emulator /bin/sh -c yes | ./sdkmanager \"ndk;${NDK_VERSION_1}\" \"ndk;${NDK_VERSION_2}\" \"ndk;${NDK_VERSION_3}\" --sdk_root=/opt/cmdline-tools/latest/bin" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.


I figured that if I use
ARG NDK_VERSION_1=23.1.7779620
ARG NDK_VERSION_2=24.0.8215888
ARG NDK_VERSION_3=25.0.8775105

It would work. But I searched and found that NDK 21+ do support ARM64. So I'm not sure why it's giving this error.
Does anyone have an idea?
This is a part of my Dockerfile
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 ghcr.io/actions/actions-runner:latest

# Set environment variables
ENV HOME=/home/runner
ENV ANDROID_HOME="/opt/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/"
ENV RUBY_VERSION=2.7.8
ENV RUBY_VERSION_UPDATE=3.2.2

ENV LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

# # Run as root user
USER root
WORKDIR /root/
# Set non-interactive frontend for apt-get
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Define versions for various tools and packages
ARG WM_VERSION=v2021.03.01.00
ARG NODE_VERSION=16.0.0
ARG NPM_VERSION=7.10.0

ARG GRADLE_VERSION=gradle-7.4.1

ARG ANDROID_SDK_VERSION=commandlinetools-linux-7583922_latest

ARG SDK_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION_1=30.0.3
ARG SDK_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION_2=31.0.0
ARG SDK_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION_3=33.0.0
ARG SDK_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION_4=33.0.1
ARG SDK_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION_5=34.0.0

ARG SKD_PLATFORMS_1=android-30
ARG SKD_PLATFORMS_2=android-31
ARG SKD_PLATFORMS_3=android-33
ARG SKD_PLATFORMS_4=android-34

# NDK Versions
ARG NDK_VERSION_1=21.4.7075529
ARG NDK_VERSION_2=23.1.7779620
ARG NDK_VERSION_3=24.0.8215888

ARG CMAKE_VERSION_1=3.18.1
ARG CMAKE_VERSION_2=3.22.1

ARG JAVA_VERSION=openjdk-17-jdk

# Install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --fix-missing \
    wget \
    npm \
    ruby-full \
    rbenv \
    git \
    jq \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    imagemagick \
    locales \
    libyaml-dev \
    && locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Compile and install curl from source
# RUN wget https://curl.se/download/curl-8.4.0.tar.gz \
#     && tar -xvf curl-8.4.0.tar.gz \
#     && cd curl-8.4.0 \
#     && ./configure --with-openssl \
#     && make \
#     && make install \
#     && cd .. \
#     && rm -rf curl-8.4.0 curl-8.4.0.tar.gz \
#     && ln -sf /usr/local/bin/curl /usr/bin/curl \
#     && ldconfig \
  
# Using package manager's curl which gets the latest supported curl for arm64. curl 8.4.0 is not supported.
  RUN apt-get install curl \
    # Download and install kubectl
    && curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/arm64/kubectl" \
    && chmod +x ./kubectl \
    && mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl \
    # Install and setup Gradle
    && mkdir /opt/gradle \
    && cd /opt/gradle \
    && wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/$GRADLE_VERSION-all.zip \
    && unzip -d /opt/gradle $GRADLE_VERSION-all.zip \
    && rm /opt/gradle/$GRADLE_VERSION-all.zip \
    && ln -s /opt/gradle/${GRADLE_VERSION}/bin/gradle /usr/local/bin/gradle \
    # Setup Ruby environment using rbenv
    && git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv \
    && echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc \
    && echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc \
    && echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile \
    && echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile \
    && git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git "$(rbenv root)"/plugins/ruby-build \
    && rbenv install $RUBY_VERSION && rbenv global $RUBY_VERSION \
    && rbenv install $RUBY_VERSION_UPDATE \
    && ruby --version \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Install Bundler
RUN gem install bundler:2.4.22 --no-document

# Install awscli
RUN pip install awscli

# Install Node.js and npm
RUN npm install -g npmrc && \
    npm i -g penv && \
    npm install eslint -g && \
    npm install yarn -g

# Install Android SDK
WORKDIR /opt
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN  apt-get update && apt-get install -y ${JAVA_VERSION}\
  && wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/$ANDROID_SDK_VERSION.zip \ 
  && export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/toolsi \
  && export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools \
  && unzip ${ANDROID_SDK_VERSION}.zip && rm ${ANDROID_SDK_VERSION}.zip \
  && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Configure Android SDK and platforms
# Set the working directory once
WORKDIR /opt/cmdline-tools

# Move files to 'latest' directory
RUN mkdir latest && mv NOTICE.txt bin lib source.properties latest

# Set the working directory to where sdkmanager is located
WORKDIR /opt/cmdline-tools/latest/bin

# Now run sdkmanager commands without needing to cd each time
RUN yes | ./sdkmanager --licenses --sdk_root=/opt/cmdline-tools/latest/bin

RUN ./sdkmanager --list

RUN yes | ./sdkmanager "tools" "platform-tools" --sdk_root=/opt/cmdline-tools/latest/bin || echo "Emulator not available, continuing..."

RUN yes | ./sdkmanager "build-tools;${SDK_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION_1}" "build-tools;${SDK_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION_2}" "build-tools;${SDK_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION_3}" "build-tools;${SDK_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION_4}" "build-tools;${SDK_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION_5}" --sdk_root=/opt/cmdline-tools/latest/bin || echo "Emulator not available, continuing..."

RUN yes | ./sdkmanager "platforms;${SKD_PLATFORMS_1}" "platforms;${SKD_PLATFORMS_2}" "platforms;${SKD_PLATFORMS_3}" "platforms;${SKD_PLATFORMS_4}" --sdk_root=/opt/cmdline-tools/latest/bin

RUN yes | ./sdkmanager "ndk;${NDK_VERSION_1}" "ndk;${NDK_VERSION_2}" "ndk;${NDK_VERSION_3}" --sdk_root=/opt/cmdline-tools/latest/bin

RUN yes | ./sdkmanager "cmake;${CMAKE_VERSION_1}" "cmake;${CMAKE_VERSION_2}" --sdk_root=/opt/cmdline-tools/latest/bin

RUN chmod 777 .

I tried changing the NDK versions to a newer one and it worked, but I'd prefer to use the old version.

The problematic version is on the list of NDK versions which are no longer supported: https://github.com/android/ndk/wiki/Unsupported-Downloads
